# Arduino custom library error when compiling delay()

Tags: header, include, delay, arduino

I am trying to write an adruino library but keep getting hung up on errors requiring me to include header files. I have run into one that I can't find the header file for. I keep getting the error:

```
...file.cpp:23: error: 'delay' was not declared in this scope
```

Line 23 of my .cpp file is:

```
delay(10);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have found that including Arduino.h works. If there is a better way let me know, but at any rate I found an answer. Including Arduino.h also made it so I didn't need to include any of the other header fils I was including such as WString.h, HardwareSerial.h or Stdio.h.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using a version of the Arduino software prior to 1.0 (with a version number of the form 00XY, e.g. 0023) you need to include `WProgram.h` in your .cpp files.

If you are using 1.0 or above include `Arduino.h` instead (the header file was renamed in that version).

Comment: `error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory` is what I got in return.

Comment: From Arduino version 1.0 onwards the header file has been renamed to `Arduino.h`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. Still developing on an old version :P

Answer (score 7):

change

```
  #include "WProgram.h"
```

to

```
  #if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
      #include "Arduino.h"
    #else
      #include "WProgram.h"
    #endif
```

in the offending .h header file